# Changing background color for 'asis' engine output in rmarkdown / knitr

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am writing tutorial problem sets in rmarkdown / knitr to output to PDF. I use chunks with the 'asis' engine to include solutions which only appear in the instructor's version of the document. The solutions themselves are written in markdown. 
Is there a way to have the background of the asis engine chunks being colored differently to set the solution off from the problem statement?

Putting a Latex block around this did not help as then the markdown in the chunk will not be interpreted any more.

Example rmarkdown code:

`````
1. How does the cookie crumble?

    ```{asis, echo=TRUE}
    * Into 49 pieces.
    * With a crunching noise.
    ````
`````

I would like to have a grey background for the chunk's output, similar to that of a normal R chunk's output.